# What is the default maximum url limit in Flask?

Tags: python, flask, wsgi, flask-restful, wsgiserver

I am working with Flask and WSGI Server. I am getting 414 error when i fire call with large urls(above 8k characters).

I need to find out if it is limited by the Flask or the WSGI.
Is there any default maximum size limit for urls in Flask?.

Comment: [This book](https://books.google.es/books?id=gtwiEAAAQBAJ&pg=PT27&lpg=PT27&dq=flask+byte+limit&source=bl&ots=L6PNdcB7VE&sig=ACfU3U0t4Xzvdt7sweTNcmOVjAsiqZZTOQ&hl=en&sa=X&ved=2ahUKEwiJrdiYoouAAxUXGsAKHfyPD4U4FBDoAXoECAIQAw#v=onepage&q=flask%20byte%20limit&f=false) says that there is a 2k byte limit for GET requests, though I don't know the actual limit.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to process such a huge data, I think it’s better to use POST and send the data as a request body. Don’t know about flask limit, but you should check your browser limit too, if you use it in your project.